# Proper way to pass functions to directive for execution in link

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I know we usually pass functions to directives via an isolated scope:

```js
.directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        scope:{
            foo: '&'
        }        
    };
})
```

And then in the template we can call this function like such:

```html
<button class="btn" ng-click="foo({ myVal: value })">Submit</button>
```

Where `myVal` is the name of the parameter that function `foo` in the parent scope takes.

Now if I intend to use this from the `link` function instead of template, I will have to call it with: `scope.foo()(value)`, since `scope.foo` serves as a wrapper of the original function. This seems a bit tedious to me.

If I pass the function to the `myComponent` directive using `=`:

```js
.directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        scope:{
            foo: '='
        }        
    };
})
```

Then I will be able to just use `scope.foo(value)` from my link function. So is this a valid use case to use 2-way binding on functions, or am I doing some sort of hack that I shouldn't be doing?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this per se, but maybe consider delegating to a service.

Comment: I am hesitant because 2-way binding seems to be designed for data model, but I am using it on a function. In general these functions aren't expected to be changed anyway.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is why I downvoted the answer.

First, you should never use '=' to pass function references to directives.

'=' creates two watches and uses them to ensure that both the directive scope and the parent scope references are the same (two-way binding).  It is a really bad idea to allow a directive to change the definition of a function in your parent scope, which is what happens when you use this type of binding.  Also, watches should be minimized - while it will work, the two extra $watches are unnecessary.  So it is not fine - part of the down vote was for suggesting that it was.

Second - the answer misrepresents what '&' does.  & is not a "one way binding". It gets that misnomer simply because, unlike '=', it does not create any $watches and changing the value of the property in the directive scope does not propagate to the parent.

According to the docs:

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of
>   the parent scope

When you use & in a directive, it generates a function that returns the value of the expression evaluated against the parent scope.  The expression does not have to be a function call.  It can be any valid angular expression.  In addition, this generated function takes an object argument that can override the value of any local variable found in the expression.

To extend the OP's example, suppose the parent uses this directive in the following way:

```
<my-component foo="go()">
```

In the directive (template or link function), if you call

```
foo({myVal: 42});
```

What you are doing is evaluating the expression "go()", which happens to call the function "go" on the parent scope, passing no arguments.

Alternatively,

```
<my-component foo="go(value)">
```

You are evaluating the expression "go(value)" on the parent scope, which will is basically calling $parent.go($parent.value)"

```
<my-component foo="go(myVal)">
```

You are evaluating the expression "go(myVal)", but before the expression is evaluated, myVal will be replaced with 42, so the evaluated expression will be "go(42)".

```
<my-component foo="myVal + value + go()">
```

In this case, $scope.foo({myVal: 42}) will return the result of:

```
42 + $parent.value + $parent.go()
```

Essentially, this pattern allows the directive to "inject" variables that the consumer of the directive can optionally use in the foo expression.

You could do this:

```
<my-component foo="go">
```

and in the directive:

```
$scope.foo()(42)
```

$scope.foo() will evaluate the expression "go", which will return a reference to the $parent.go function.  It will then call it as $parent.go(42).  The downside to this pattern is that you will get an error if the expression does not evaluate to a function.

The final reason for the down vote was the assertion that the ng-event directives use &.  This isn't the case.  None of the built in directives create isolated scopes with:

```
scope:{
}
```

The implementation of '&foo' is (simplified for clarity), boils down to:

```
$scope.foo = function(locals) {
    return $parse(attr.foo)($scope.$parent, locals);
}
```

The implementation of ng-click is similar, but (also simplified):

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
    elem.on('click', function(evt) {
        $parse(attr.ngClick)(scope, {
             $event: evt
        }
    });
}
```

So the key to remember is that when you use '&', you are not passing a function - you are passing an expression.  The directive can get the result of this expression at any time by invoking the generated function.

Comment: I don't see what justifies the downvote and I did the same for the same reason. One-way is just a name but I explain how it evaluates an expression. You, like me, recognize `$scope.foo()(42)` is an anti-pattern that makes little sense. Finally, `ngRepeat` does not create an isolated scope (nor does ng-click and most built in directive, I give you that, my bad), so the user can still use what pre-existed on its scope. You could have edited my answer rather than duplicating the explanations to better serve the community.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger What if the passed function is sort of callback? I.e. it needs to be called with parameters specified in the directive `link` function. Is it ok to use `=` in such situation?

Comment: If by callback you mean that your link function in your directive wants to call a function declared on the parent scope, then my advice still applies.  If you can point me to a plunkr that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish I can be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

Two-way binding to pass a function is fine as long as your function will always take the same parameters in the same order. But also useless for that purpose.

The one-way binding is more efficient and allows to call a function with any parameter and in any order, and offer more visibility in the HTML. For instance we could not imagine `ngClick` to be a two-way binding: sometimes you want something like `<div ng-click="doStuff(var1)">` up to more complex things such as

```
<div ng-click="doStuff('hardcoded', var1+4); var2 && doAlso(var2)">
```

See: you can manipulate the parameters directly from the HTML.

Now I feel like you misunderstood how to use one-way bindings. If you indeed define `onFoo: '&'` in your directive, then from the link function you should do for instance:

```
// assume bar is already in your scope
scope.bar = "yo";
// Now you can call foo like this
scope.onFoo( {extra: 42} );
```

So in your HTML you could use

```
<div on-foo="doSomething(bar, extra)">
```

Note that you have access to not only all the properties of the directive isolated scope (`bar`), but also the extra "locals" added at the moment of the call (`extra`).

Your notation like `scope.foo()(value)` looks like a hack to me, that is not the itended way to use one-way bindings.

Note: one-way bindings are typically used with some "event" functions such as `when-drop`, `on-leave`, `ng-click`, `when-it-is-loaded`, etc.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The person who did it can you please share some insight?

Comment: Thanks @Xavier_Ex, I'd be curious about that as well. If I am wrong I'm eager to learn about what exactly.